# Several Unmet peer dependency errors, including @angular/common@2.4.9

Tags: angular, npm

I've been struggling with package dependencies for the past couple of days, my goal is to use angular2-busy but i started reading about it and I think I have a bigger overall problem.

Whenver I run "`npm list`" I get a bunch of UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY messages.

I wanted to start cleaning that up and the first entry was:

```
"UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.4.9"
```

I tried re-installing @angular/common but that didn't make any difference, could somebody explain to me what's the actual issue here so I can start cleaning all this up?

Thanks.

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.4",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.4",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.4",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.4",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.2",
    "angular2-busy": "^1.0.2",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.5.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "ng2-filter-pipe": "^0.1.6",
    "ng2-toasty": "^2.3.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36",
    "@types/lodash": "ts2.0",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.4",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

Comment: Can you add your package.json to your question please?

Comment: Done. Added my package.json to the question.

Comment: Well, I guess that it complains because you have a lower version of angular than expected, change all 2.4.4 by 2.4.9 and 3.4.4 by 3.4.9, run npm install and it should be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firs of all  what you are trying to do?

`npm list` is for listing installed packages it will not install/update anything.

You should do `npm install` or `npm update`

I have copied your package.json and executed these command lines:

```
npm cache clean
npm install
npm update
```

And everything works!

To check dependencies versions try to use `npm-check-updates`

To install use this command:

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

After install from command line run `ncu` and you will see what is the latest version of the packages.

One more thing regarding version numbers in npm check this article [Node and npm Version Numbering: Guide and Best Practices](https://scotch.io/tutorials/node-and-npm-version-numbering-guide-and-best-practices)

After updates to the latest versions your `package.json` look like this:

```
   {
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.4",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.4",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.4",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.4",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.1",
    "angular2-busy": "^1.0.2",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.5.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "ng2-filter-pipe": "^0.1.6",
    "ng2-toasty": "^2.3.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.2.0",
    "systemjs": "0.20.9",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/lodash": "ts2.0",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.4",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "protractor": "~5.1.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "tslint": "^4.5.1",
    "typescript": "~2.2.1"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```